# WAR based microservice registration with Eureka Discovery Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

One of our client applications has following architecture -

1. Angular based front end
2. Spring Boot based web application to talk to front end
3. Spring Boot based microservices to talk to web application
4. Eureka Discovery client to enable web app locate microservices

Recently we faced some issue and want to make one of the microservice to be installed as application under standalone tomcat. Making microservice application main class extend SpringBootServletInitializer, and changing packaging to war helped generate war artifact and it gets deployed on tomcat, as well as registers on Eureka - but its not servicable.

When web application looks up the service via Eureka and invoked any API, it fails. Even invoking service via Postman or directly in browser fails for registered URL. It seems the microservice when exposed as web application under tomcat does not resolve via Eureka. Any suggestions?

**Configuration**:
Data service - to be deployed as war

```
spring.application.name=data-service
server.contextPath=/data-service
server.servlet.application-display-name=Data Service
spring.main.banner-mode=log
#server.port=9090
spring.jmx.default-domain=${spring.application.name}

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:9098/eureka
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.preferSameZoneEureka=true

ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
ribbon.ReadTimeout = 60000
```

When deployed, it registers with Eureka Discovery with name *data-service*, but The uri is not a correct one to reach the instance, it happens to be something like

```
GET http://data-service/query/xxxxx HTTP/1.1
```

It misses the Tomcat port 8080 and the tomcat context. Manually checking uri

> http://localhost:8080/data-service/query/xxxxx

does work.

Comment: Please provide any logs available on the service that runs on Tomcat. Also, directly call your service from postman and see whats the result. It may not be accessible through that tomcat (note that you are using the running tomcat port).

Comment: @SepGH, Tomcat logs are clean, the application deploys successfully. Directly calling service with http://localhost:8080/data-service/query/xxxxx works. It somehow while registering with Eureka has wrong context path/uri set as http://data-service/query/xxxxx